# Nut/sunflower butter and cocoa

Tags: food-safety, nut-butters

A family member mixed sunflower butter, cocoa, sugar and a bit of milk (stirred in, not thoroughly mixed in) and left it in the fridge for quite a long time, a month or so. I want to wash it out but this isn't any sort of botulism risk is it? If it is it would be very hard to clean and I would rather throw out the bowl. I still am confused about leaving something fatty with something else and thinking that it's coating whatever it's mixed with and getting sort of anaerobic. I don't understand why nut butters don't have a problem either but it seems they don't. I know there are commercial chocolate nut butters but I assume they are pasteurized and processed together making them safe.

I did read this question but am still confused. [Chocolate and oil mixed](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56944/chocolate-and-oil-mixed)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Are you concerned about the health risks from washing out the bowl?

Comment: Basically yes, as it would be hard to be sure it was all gone off of the dishes, sink, etc. (being greasy). And would there be anything there to be concerned about in the first place or not with foods like nut butters mixed with other substances? Thanks.